# Modern Mac clipboard archiver

Tags: macos, clipboard

I've always used [Jumpcut](http://jumpcut.sourceforge.net/), but it seems to be acting strangely on macOS 10.13 (High Sierra).  It hasn't been updated since January 2009.  Does anyone know of an alternative?  Jumpcut will remember things that have been copied to the clipboard, so you can get them later.

Answer (score 1):

I find [Pasteapp](http://pasteapp.me) is a nice Clipboardmanager.

- List item
- Unlimeted history
- iCloudsync
- Quick Look
- Paste multiple items
- Clipboard sharing

Answer (score 1):

[LaunchBar](https://obdev.at/products/launchbar) has a powerful clipboard manager included.

Comment: I've not used it (yet?), but it surely looks nice, also for _"Combine subsequent Copy operations into one single clipboard object by just pressing ⌘C twice."_ But alas, seeing it mentioning OS X rather than macOS made me wonder if it is still maintained in 2022. And yes: today [the last version is December 13, 2021](https://obdev.at/products/launchbar/releasenotes.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Nice Clipboard** is an app I use on my Mac and iPad. It's a clipboard manager that will save all the 'copies' you make. It can save any number of 'copies' up to unlimited. It provides a menu bar icon to make it always available. It works with iCloud so its contents are available on other of your Mac devices. The app sells for $2.99 at the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

[Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) can be used as a clipboard manager. Advanced macros can write clipboard content to a file.